# How to cross-reference a block2 custom block?

Tags: bookdown

I am using bookdown to create a 'book', and have some custom blocks declared using the `block2`, as per Section 2.7 in Yihui Xie's book (https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html).

How can I cross-reference to these blocks?

For example, suppose I have this, directly from Yihui's book:

````
```{block2, type='FOO'}
Some text for this block [@citation-key].

- a list item
- another item

More text.
```
````

How can I cross-reference to it (like one can with, say, `example` blocks), using `\@ref()`? Perhaps I missed it in the book.

Yihiu's book states that "The theorem and proof environments in Section 2.2.2 are actually implemented through the `block2` engine"... so presumably cross-referencing is possible with a `block2` custom block.

Any ideas for naive me?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot cross-reference these blocks (at least for now). They are not numbered. Theorem environments have some special treatments in **bookdown**, and they are not generalized to arbitrary custom blocks.

Comment: too bad, I would really have liked that, too...